# Replace strings in dex file

Tags: android, dex

I need to replace a string in a dex file. That is, I need a tool (free and open-sourced) that receives dex file, string index and new string value as input parameters and produces new (patched) dex file.

It shouldn't be too hard to write by myself, but maybe there's a tool that does exactly what I need and can save me time.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali ?

Comment: @fadden Haven't found a command line flag that does exactly what I need. I'm pretty sure that I can extract the above logic from smali project though, but I'm looking for 'end product'.

Comment: @AlexLipov: are you able to find any solution? I am looking for something same.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of an existing end-to-end solution. Your best bet would be to use dexlib2. In particular, the [DexRewriter](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/blob/master/dexlib2/src/main/java/org/jf/dexlib2/rewriter/DexRewriter.java) class is a good example of how to go about doing this sort of replacement, although it doesn't directly support string replacement.

I don't think modifying a string in the string table is actually what you want. Keep in mind that strings can be used for a number of things in a dex file: string constants, method names, field names, class names, etc. If you just want to change a string constant, you would need to find and replace all instances of where that string is used as a string constant. If you try to replace *all* instances of that string, you might end up inadvertently modifying a field name, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a little late answering but hopefully others who come across this can benefit.  The sable soot library (https://github.com/sable/soot) offers tools to modify Android APK files code.  Once the library is set up then swapping out a single string is not too bad.